# redirect and refresh html page, onclick image from other page

Tags: javascript, html, telerik

i am building a mobile app in Telerik Tool. on footer i have placed some of icons like

contacts, groups, chat etc. when i click on footer icon it redirect fine. i get problem

after redirecting page, it wont get refresh by itself. need to refresh(simulator

refresh button-Telerik tool).

```
<div class="nav" data-id="oneFooter" id="page-location-footer" data-position="fixed">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="35%">
                            <a href="contacts.html">
                                    <img src="images/user.png" alt="Smiley face"  
width="40" height="40">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="35%">
                                <a href="groups.html">
                                    <img src="images/images.jpg" alt="Smiley face" 
width="40" height="40">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                          <td width="35%">
                                <a href="metext.html">
                                    <img src="images/chat.png" alt="Smiley face" 
width="40" height="40">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="35%">
                                <a href="social.html">
                                    <img src="images/images1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" 
width="40" height="40">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

so all i need is Redirect page from page to other page onclick of image and get

refresh the redirected page.

Kindly do needful...

Comment: why would you need a refresh after redirecting ?

Comment: "`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`"

Comment: i ll keep in mid this thing Mr.Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the `http-equiv` meta tag with a refresh value.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

(You imply in the question that redirect is working fine, so I'm not touching that.)

To have the refresh only happen once, rather than continually at an interval, you can use javascript [reload()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) in an if statement which depends upon the value of the [HTTP referer [sic] header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

Comment: ya Parthian Shot, redirect is working fine, may i know how to use meta tag to refresh only once. i dont want to refresh page after some interval. I am new to stack overflow and using HTML and JavaScript, if any thing wrong, pleas dont mind.

Comment: i will use javascript Parthian, it will better i think. Thanks a lot Mr.Parthian Shot